# Converting from \unnnn to letters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a file with letters stored like this

```
\u0410\u0411\u0426
```

I want to conver them in something readable 
for example the `\u0410\u0411\u0426` means `АБЦ`

but I do not know anything about why is A stored as `\u0410` or why is `Б` stored as `\u0411`.
 how can I do the conversion between this two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo -e '\u0410\u0411\u0426'
АБЦ
$ printf '\u0410\u0411\u0426'
АБЦ
$ python3 -c 'print("\u0410\u0411\u0426")'
АБЦ
$ echo '\u0410\u0411\u0426' | ascii2uni -qaU
АБЦ
```

Comment: just to clarify: the last one can be used for the "file" with ascii2uni -qaU <file

Comment: None of them works in bash 4.1.5, but `echo АБЦ` works, so no encoding issues there. Do you apply any special settings?

Comment: @A.H. I'm using `Ubuntu 11.10` with `GNU Bash-4.2`. No special settings.

Comment: @A.H maybe you need sudo apt-get install python3-minimal. But how do I convert from АБЦ to \u0410\u0411\u0426 ?

Comment: @Lukap. `for i in 'АБЦ': print(hex(ord(i)))`

Comment: this doesn't works for me "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('"
, it prints the same with ...ord($i)...

Comment: @Lukap. Sorry, It's `python3` code. Please try `python3 -c 'for i in "АБЦ": print(hex(ord(i)))'`

Comment: @Lukap: Regarding python3-minimal tip: It seems, that the conversion from \uXXXX to Unicode is done by the shell in all four cases. It is OK for me to have a shell to old for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
#irb -E binary
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > s="\u0410\u0411\u0426"
 => "\u0410\u0411\u0426" 

#irb -E utf-8
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > s="\u0410\u0411\u0426"
 => "АБЦ"
```

you have to read something about character encodings, [unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)